# jconsole not able to connect to remote process

Tags: java, keystore, jconsole

I am not able to connect to a remote java process which is started with following parameters:

> ```
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
> ```

If I want to connect with jconsole to this remote process (server.company-service:9010) I get following error message in jconsole debugging window:

> ```
> Cipher: Crypto Permission check failed 
> Cipher: granted: (CryptoPermission * 128) 
> Cipher: requesting: (CryptoPermission AES 256)
> ```

So, I already imported certificate in java keystore but it seems that the encryption is wrong.

**Question:**
How to solve this problem? I am using Java 6.

Comment: Did you succeed in the end?

Comment: This issue contains a similar bug output: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8532828/1143126 Please check the answers, the unlimited strength cryptography policy file part may be of interest to you.

Comment: @RobertG found no solution so far. Thanks for response! Will check the linked answers soon :-)!